# Delphi: getting list of handles/files in use by a process in Windows 10 v. 1607

Tags: delphi, winapi

Edit: the problem didn't lie in NtQuerySystemInformation but in the file type (bObjectType) having changed in this new edition of Windows 10 to the value 34. in Creators Update it's 35.

I have been using the following code successfully to retrieve a list of files in use by a given process, but since the Windows 10 "anniversary update" it's no longer working.

Windows 10 version 1607 Build 14393.105

Any idea?

```
function GetFileNameHandle(hFile: THandle): String;
var lpExitCode: DWORD;
    pThreadParam: TGetFileNameThreadParam;
    hThread: THandle;
    Ret: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := '';
  ZeroMemory(@pThreadParam, SizeOf(TGetFileNameThreadParam));
  pThreadParam.hFile := hFile;
  hThread := CreateThread(nil, 0, @GetFileNameHandleThr, @pThreadParam, 0, {PDWORD(nil)^} Ret);
  if hThread <> 0 then
  try
    case WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 100) of
      WAIT_OBJECT_0: begin
        GetExitCodeThread(hThread, lpExitCode);
        if lpExitCode = STATUS_SUCCESS then
          Result := pThreadParam.FileName;
      end;
      WAIT_TIMEOUT: TerminateThread(hThread, 0);
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(hThread);
  end;
end;

procedure DeleteUpToFull(var src: String; UpTo: String);
begin
  Delete(src,1,Pos(Upto,src)+Length(UpTo)-1);
end;

procedure ConvertDevicePath(var dvc: string);
var i: integer;
    root: string;
    device: string;
    buffer: string;
    //drvs: string;
begin
  // much faster without using GetReadyDiskDrives
  setlength(buffer, 1000);
  for i := Ord('a') to Ord('z') do begin
    root := Chr(i) + ':';
    if (QueryDosDevice(PChar(root), pchar(buffer), 1000) <> 0) then begin
      device := pchar(buffer);
      if finds(device+'\',dvc) then begin
        DeleteUpToFull(dvc,device+'\');
        dvc := root[1] + ':\' + dvc;
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

//get the pid of the process which had open the specified file
function GetHandlesByProcessID(const ProcessID: Integer; Results: TStringList; TranslatePaths: Boolean): Boolean;
var hProcess    : THandle;
    hFile       : THandle;
    ReturnLength: DWORD;
    SystemInformationLength : DWORD;
    Index       : Integer;
    pHandleInfo : PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION;
    hQuery      : THandle;
    FileName    : string;
    r: byte;
begin
  Result := False;
  Results.Clear;
  pHandleInfo      := nil;
  ReturnLength     := 1024;
  pHandleInfo      := AllocMem(ReturnLength);
  hQuery           := NTQuerySystemInformation(DWORD(SystemHandleInformation), pHandleInfo, 1024, @ReturnLength);
  r := 0; // loop safe-guard
  While (hQuery = $C0000004) and (r < 10) do begin
    Inc(r);
    FreeMem(pHandleInfo);
    SystemInformationLength := ReturnLength;
    pHandleInfo             := AllocMem(ReturnLength+1024);
    hQuery                  := NTQuerySystemInformation(DWORD(SystemHandleInformation), pHandleInfo, SystemInformationLength, @ReturnLength);//Get the list of handles
  end;
  // if hQuery = 0 then
  //  RaiseLastOSError;

  try
    if (hQuery = STATUS_SUCCESS) then begin
     for Index := 0 to pHandleInfo^.uCount-1 do begin
       // filter to requested process
       if pHandleInfo.Handles[Index].uIdProcess <> ProcessID then Continue;
       // http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18975/Listing-Used-Files
       // For an object of type file, the value bObjectType in SYSTEM_HANDLE is 28 in Windows XP, Windows 2000, and Window 7; 25 in Windows Vista; and 26 in Windows 2000.
       // XP = 28
       // W7 = 28
       // W8 = 31
       if (pHandleInfo.Handles[Index].ObjectType < 25) or
         (pHandleInfo.Handles[Index].ObjectType > 31) then Continue;

        hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, FALSE, pHandleInfo.Handles[Index].uIdProcess);
        if(hProcess <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then begin
          try
           if not DuplicateHandle(hProcess, pHandleInfo.Handles[Index].Handle,
                                  GetCurrentProcess(), @hFile,  0 ,FALSE,
                                  DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS) then
            hFile := INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
          finally
           CloseHandle(hProcess);
          end;

          if (hFile <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then begin
            try
              FileName := GetFileNameHandle(hFile);
            finally
              CloseHandle(hFile);
            end;
          end
          else
          FileName := '';

          if FileName <> '' then begin
            if TranslatePaths then begin
                ConvertDevicePath(FileName);
                if not FileExists(Filename) then FileName := '\##\'+Filename; //Continue;
            end;
            Results.Add(FileName);
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    if pHandleInfo <> nil then FreeMem(pHandleInfo);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Please make a MCVE for us

Comment: hQuery(NTSTATUS) is 0 - this is not error but ok code. and NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemHandleInformation) fine work on 10 version 1607 as well. i checked this

Comment: and you must not hardcode object types indexes but got this info from system

Comment: Sorry, you are right, the problem lies elsewhere. I'll check again and edit the question.

Comment: @hikari NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemHandleInformation) must return STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH (c0000004) for 1024 size buffer.. dont know why you got 0. but i claim that SystemHandleInformation and SystemExtendedHandleInformation correct worked on latest win10 build (1607 x64) - i permanent use this calls in self code

Comment: @RbMm: Pointing out what's wrong is helpful. If you know, how to properly implement it, provide some more details. It need not necessarily be Delphi code in a comment. Someone fluent in Delphi can probably translate C code easily, and likely compose an answer.

Comment: @IInspectable - yes, ofcourse i know how implement this. however hikari code look like correct for this point. very not optimal, but must work

Comment: Found the issue, bObjectType = 34 for this new W10 and I was only including 25-31.

Comment: @hikari - "Found the issue, bObjectType = 34" - this is wat i say - you need not hardcode this indexes by got in in runtime. i show how in answer

Comment: @hikari - also this mean that "hQuery is 0 after .." is not true ?

Comment: edit: bObjectType = 35 in W10 Creators Update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next code (in C++) works 100% correct on all Windows versions (Win 10 1607 as well). Also, I use `SystemExtendedHandleInformation` in place of `SystemHandleInformation`, and advise you to do so, too.  It is present from XP onwards. However, the code with `SystemHandleInformation` also works correctly, I just checked it.

```cpp
NTSTATUS GetHandlesByProcessID()
{
    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION_EX pshti;
    };

    NTSTATUS status;
    ULONG ReturnLength = 1024;//not reasonable value for start query,but let be
    ULONG UniqueProcessId = GetCurrentProcessId(); 
    do 
    {
        status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;

        if (buf = new BYTE[ReturnLength])
        {
            if (0 <= (status = ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemExtendedHandleInformation, buf, ReturnLength, &ReturnLength)))
            {
                if (ULONG_PTR NumberOfHandles = pshti->NumberOfHandles)
                {
                    SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO_EX* Handles = pshti->Handles;
                    do 
                    {
                        if (Handles->UniqueProcessId == UniqueProcessId)
                        {
                            DbgPrint("%u, %p\n", Handles->ObjectTypeIndex, Handles->HandleValue);
                        }
                    } while (Handles++, --NumberOfHandles);
                }
            }

            delete buf;
        }

    } while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);

    return status;
}
```

I think this is like a `repeat until` in a Delphi loop :)

`r := 0; // loop safe-guard` - this is not needed.

About the hard-coded `ObjectTypeIndex` - beginning in Win 8.1, you can exactly get this info from the OS. You need to call [`ZwQueryObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567062(v=vs.85).aspx) with  [`ObjectTypesInformation`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntobapi_8h_source.html#l00034) (in some sources, this is named `ObjectAllTypeInformation`, see ntifs.h) to get an array of [`OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntobapi_8h_source.html#l00068) structs. Look for the [`TypeIndex`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntobapi_8h_source.html#l00088) member - it exactly cooresponds to the [`ObjectTypeIndex`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntexapi_8h_source.html#l01871) from [`SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO_EX`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntexapi_8h_source.html#l01864).  Before Win 8.1, there also exists ways to get this 'on the fly' by using `ObjectAllTypeInformation` but it is more complex.

Comment: Could you provide an example in Delphi for that?

Comment: @hikari - no, i dont't know Delphi. i programming only on *c++03*

Answer (score 2):

I just tested the code from my blog article "[Running multiple instances of Microsoft Lync](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2012/03/07/running-multiple-instances-of-lync-howto/)" on Windows 10 Anniversary Update on it appears to work without any issues.

Here's the code that I tested (takes process name eg foobar.exe as parameter):

```
program ListHandles;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  JwaWinBase,
  JwaWinNT,
  JwaWinType,
  JwaNtStatus,
  JwaNative,
  JwaWinsta,
  SysUtils,
  StrUtils;

{$IFDEF RELEASE}
  // Leave out Relocation Table in Release version
  {$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_RELOCS_STRIPPED}
{$ENDIF RELEASE}
{$SetPEOptFlags IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE}

// No need for RTTI
{$WEAKLINKRTTI ON}
 {$RTTI EXPLICIT METHODS([]) PROPERTIES([]) FIELDS([])}

var
  dwPid: DWORD;
  hProcess: THandle;

{$ALIGN 8}
{$MINENUMSIZE 4}
type
  _SYSTEM_HANDLE = record
    ProcessId: ULONG;
    ObjectTypeNumber: Byte;
    Flags: Byte;
    Handle: USHORT;
    _Object: PVOID;
    GrantedAccess: ACCESS_MASK;
  end;
  SYSTEM_HANDLE = _SYSTEM_HANDLE;
  PSYSTEM_HANDLE = ^SYSTEM_HANDLE;

  _SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION = record
    HandleCount: ULONG;
    Handles: array[0..0] of SYSTEM_HANDLE;
  end;
  SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION = _SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION;
  PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION = ^SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION;

  _OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION = record
    Length: USHORT;
    MaximumLength: USHORT;
    Pad: DWORD;
    Name: array[0..MAX_PATH-1] of Char;
  end;
  OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION = _OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION;
  POBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION = ^OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION;

function GetObjectName(const hObject: THandle): String;
var
  oni: OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION;
  cbSize: DWORD;
  nts: NTSTATUS;
begin
  Result := '';

  cbSize := SizeOf(oni) - (2 * SizeOf(USHORT));
  oni.Length := 0;
  oni.MaximumLength := cbSize;
  nts := NtQueryObject(hObject, ObjectNameInformation, @oni, cbSize, @cbSize);
  if (nts = STATUS_SUCCESS) and (oni.Length > 0) then
  begin
    Result := oni.Name;
  end;
end;

function GetCurrentSessionId: DWORD;
 asm
   mov     eax,fs:[$00000018];   // Get TEB
   mov     eax,[eax+$30];        // PPEB
   mov     eax,[eax+$1d4];       // PEB.SessionId
 end;

function GetProcessByName(const ProcessName: string): DWORD;
var
  ProcName: PChar;
  Count: Integer;
  tsapi: PTS_ALL_PROCESSES_INFO_ARRAY;
  i: Integer;
  dwSessionId: DWORD;
begin
  Result := 0;
  tsapi := nil;

  if not WinStationGetAllProcesses(SERVERNAME_CURRENT, 0, Count, tsapi) then
    Exit;

  ProcName := PChar(ProcessName);
  dwSessionId := GetCurrentSessionId;

  WriteLn(Format('Looking for Process %s in Session %d',
    [ProcessName, dwSessionId]));

  for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
  begin
    with tsapi^[i], tsapi^[i].pTsProcessInfo^ do
    begin
      if (dwSessionId = SessionId) and (ImageName.Buffer <> nil) and
        (StrIComp(ProcName, ImageName.Buffer) = 0) then
      begin
        Result := UniqueProcessId;
        WriteLn(Format('%s has Pid %d', [ProcessName, Result]));
        Break
      end;
    end;
  end;

  if tsapi <> nil then
    WinStationFreeGAPMemory(0, tsapi, Count);
end;

procedure EnumHandles;
var
  shi: PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION;
  cbSize: DWORD;
  cbRet: DWORD;
  nts: NTSTATUS;
  i: Integer;
  hDupHandle: THandle;
  dwErr: DWORD;
  ObjectName: string;
begin
  WriteLn('Enumerating Handles');
  cbSize := $5000;
  GetMem(shi, cbSize);
  repeat
    cbSize := cbSize * 2;
    ReallocMem(shi, cbSize);
    nts := NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemHandleInformation, shi, cbSize, @cbRet);
  until nts <> STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH;

  if nts = STATUS_SUCCESS then
  begin
    for i := 0 to shi^.HandleCount - 1 do
    begin
      if shi^.Handles[i].GrantedAccess <> $0012019f then
      begin
        if shi^.Handles[i].ProcessId = dwPid then
        begin
          nts := NtDuplicateObject(hProcess, shi^.Handles[i].Handle,
            GetCurrentProcess, @hDupHandle, 0, 0, 0);

          if nts = STATUS_SUCCESS then
          begin
            ObjectName := GetObjectName(hDupHandle);
            if (ObjectName <> '') then
            begin
              WriteLn(Format('Handle=%d Name=%s', [shi^.Handles[i].Handle, ObjectName]));
              CloseHandle(hDupHandle);
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end
  else begin
    dwErr := RtlNtStatusToDosError(nts);
    WriteLn(Format('Failed to read handles, NtQuerySystemInformation failed with %.8x => %d (%s)', [nts, SysErrorMessage(dwErr)]));
  end;

  FreeMem(shi);
end;


procedure AnyKey;
begin
    WriteLn('Finished');
    WriteLn('Press any key to continue');
    ReadLn;
end;

begin
  try
    dwPid := GetProcessByName(ParamStr(1));
    if dwPid = 0 then
    begin
      WriteLn('Process was not found, exiting.');
      Exit;
    end;

    WriteLn(Format('Opening Process %d with PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE', [dwPid]));
    hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, False, dwPid);

    if hProcess = 0 then
    begin
      WriteLn(Format('OpenProcess failed with %s', [SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)]));
      Exit;
    end
    else begin
      WriteLn(Format('Process Handle is %d', [hProcess]));
    end;

    EnumHandles;

  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: That asm is dodgy, use `GetCurrentProcessId` and then `ProcessIdToSessionId`

Comment: We're in the land of undocumented api's so I don't think that asm will hurt (it's documented on MSDN btw)

Comment: In fact it is documented on MSDN to use `GetCurrentProcessId` and then `ProcessIdToSessionId` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432286.aspx

Comment: Yes I know that link, if you read on you'll see that `ProcessIdToSessionId` is Vista/2008 up (so doesn't work on XP/2003 according to MSDN). That's the reason I originally used this asm. But fair enough for x64 and future win versions might be better to leave it out...